# What does Oracle error "ORA-17432: invalid options in all7" mean?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I got the following SQLException: "invalid options in all7"

Upon googling the error message, the ONLY hits I saw were Oracle error lists which pinpointed the error at **"ORA-17432: invalid options in all7"**. Sadly, googling for the error # brought up only combined lists with no explanation for the error, aside from [this page](http://www.dbmotive.com/oracle_error_codes.php?errcode=17432&type=ORA) that said "A TTC Error Message" as the entire explanation.

The error happens when a Java program retrieves data from a prepared statement call executing a procedure that returns a fairly large, but not unreasonable, # of rows via a cursor.

I can add the stack trace from the exception as well as condensed code, but I assume that's not terribly relevant to figuring out what "ORA-17432: invalid options in all7" means.

**Context**:

Error seemed to have appeared when the Java program was migrated from Oracle 9 OCI to Oracle 10.2 thin client. The procedure, when run directly against database (via Toad) works perfectly fine and returns the correct cursor with correct data and no errors.

This seems to be something data specific (result set size may be?) since running that same exact code against a different currency as a procedure parameter (which returns much smaller resultset) works 100% fine.

Comment: I can't find anything meaningfull on Metalink on this either....

Comment: Post the query & how you are calling it via JDBC.

Comment: TTC seems to be related to conversion of character set or type, when data is exchanged between client and server: 
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28316/glossary.htm#BGBFHHJG and http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/jdbcthin.htm#CACGGDCE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Akohchi - you were in the right area though not quite correct. The explanation obtained via Oracle Support call was that this version of Java (1.3) was not compatible with new Oracle. Java 1.4 fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is almost certainly not something you're going to have control of. It looks like a problem with the way your thin driver is using the two-task common (TTC) protocol. One thing to note is that this sort of thing can be very sensitive to the version of the driver you are using. Make absolutely certain that you have the latest version of the JDBC driver for the combination of the version of Java you're using and the version of Oracle on the server.